# xCode 7 - dyld`dyld_fatal_error:

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

When I was attempting to run my game (the code was generated by unity), I can get all the way to run the game in the simulator (for iPhone 5S - as thats the phone I have) but when I go to try and run it on my real iPhone, It will install, and then it will try to run, but I get a blank screen, and on my computer theres the error:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200a5088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

and beside the second line is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1200a5088)
```

---

The app will only open if xcode is trying to run it, but it will freeze, and if you just try click into the app on the actual phone it will quit out straight away.....

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Make sure to add any framework in embedded binary as well, in General tab.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and resolved it by doing a hard clean (Cmd + Shift + Opt + K) and then re-building.

Comment: Do you mean "Clean Folder"? Cuz thats just Cmd + Opt + K

Comment: In Xcode 8, Cmd + Option + K is bound by default to Debug > Debug Workflow > Reload Console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go into Build settings -> Configuration -> Scripting Backend -> Mono2x (not IL2CPP)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred in Xcode 8.  Found out that I am using a device of iOS 9.  Same app run but no problem found in another iOS 10 device.
It seems that this occur when debugging only.  The release app has no problem after installing via iTune.